# Equating coefficients cubic equation....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm dumbstruck on this elementary problem.

I have a cubic $$z = x^3 - x^2 + \frac{K+a}{b} x -\frac{a}{b}$$

I want to derive the conditions for this to have a repeated root in parametric form. The answer that is required is the following: $$\frac{K+a}{b} = \frac{2\theta + 1}{(2+\theta)^2}, \hspace{2mm} \frac{a}{b} = \frac{\theta}{(2+\theta)^3}$$

The solutions do this by expanding $z = (x-\alpha)^2(x-\theta \alpha)$ and comparing coefficients.

However I am wondering why my chosen form of the cubic does not yield the same parametrisation...

---

I let $z = (x+p)^2(x+q) = x^3 + (2p+q)x^2 + (2pq+p^2)x + p^2q$.

Comparing coefficients gives $2p + q = -1$, $2pq+p^2 = \frac{K+a}{b}$, $p^2q = -\frac{a}{b}$.

But now this does not yield the condition stated above in an obvious just yet. I have tried letting $p=\theta$, but this is not fruitful, which I'm guessing is because my $\theta$ has a different 'value' to the $\theta$ in the given condition.

> How would I obtain the conditions from **my starting point**?*

Comment: I don't know too much about the subject, but I can see that $p=\frac{-1}{2+\theta}$ and $q = \frac{-\theta}{2+\theta}$ meet the requirements.

Comment: @TimDikland Thank you, how did you notice this?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally clicked on your post. Then I chose a candidate solution and it just worked ;) However, this solution follows directly from the hint of Yves Daoust.

Comment: $2p + q = -1$ gives you  $q=-1-2p$ which you can substitute into $2pq+p^2 = \frac{K+a}{b}$ and solve the quadratic to give two possible values for $p$ and corresponding values for $q$.  Substitute these into $p^2q = -\frac{a}{b}$ and you get the two possible required relations between $K,a,b$ that provide a repeated root to the original cubic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep going. You have $q=-1-2p$. Substitute that into the other two equations to get $$\frac ab = p^2(2p+1), \frac{K+a}b = -p(3p+2).$$ Now set $p^2(2p+1)=\theta/(\theta+3)^3$ and solve for $p$. One of the solutions is $p=-1/(2+\theta)$. Substituting that into the above equalities and rearranging produces the required answer.

Comment: Actually, working with the other equation, $-p(3p+2)=(2\theta+1)/(2+\theta)^2$, is easier since that’s only quadratic in $p$ and there are only two solutions to examine.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By the Vieta formulas, with the roots $\alpha,\alpha,\theta\alpha$ you must have

$$(\theta+2)\alpha=1,\\(2\theta+1)\alpha^2=\frac{K+a}b,\\\theta\alpha^3=\frac ab.$$

Then eliminate $\alpha$.

Comment: No sorry, I know how to get the answer using their formula. I want to get the result using my starting point as clearly stated in bold...

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove: what is your "**starting point**" ??

Comment: Copied directly: "I let $z = (x+p)^2(x+q) = x^3 + (2p+q)x^2 + (2pq+p^2)x + p^2q$. 

Comparing coefficients gives $2p + q = -1$, $2pq+p^2 = \frac{K+a}{b}$, $p^2q = -\frac{a}{b}$. 

But now this does not yield the bifurcation condition obviously just yet. I have tried letting $p=\theta$, but this is not fruitful, which I'm guessing is because my $\theta$ has a different 'value' to the $\theta$ in the given condition. 

> How would I obtain the conditions from **my starting point**?*"

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove: please explain "this does not yield the bifurcation condition obviously just yet". I am not versed in the Theory of Catastrophes.

Comment: It does not give the condition for turning points to occur.